# Hotchocolate: Attaching field resolver with a flattened entity structure

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I have my entities defined as

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntityDetails: MyEntity
{

    public string ExtendedField1 { get; set; }
    public string ExtendedField2 { get; set; }
    // ...etc
}
```

The entity object type looks like this

```
public class MyEntityObjectType : ObjectType<MyEntity>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<MyEntity> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field<MyEntityDetailsResolver>(
            t => t.GetDetailsAsync())
            .Name("details")
            .Type<NonNullType<myEntityDetailsType>>();
    }
}
```

This exposes one 'details' field with MyEntity.

Now, I want to flatten the structure if possible, as that seems more logical. At the same time, I wish not to have to attach the resolver with multiple calls to `descriptor.field` for each extended property after flattening. Is there an elegant approach for that? Is there any attribute that could be specified on the Model properties itself to specify its resolver, or, some other way?

Comment: so you want the fields ExtendedField1 and ExtendedField2 to be lifted into the MyEntity type? This can be done with the descriptor attributes of 10.3.5. If that is what you want give me a ping and I post you an example.

Comment: @MichaelIngmarStaib I'm looking to do that. Can you point me to that example?

Comment: Have you joined our slack channel?

Comment: May I have a link to the Slack channel?